# Escaping probability for a poisson random walk

Tags: random-walk, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

**Poisson random walk:** Let independent random variables $Z_i \sim Pois(\lambda)$. Consider random walk 
$
S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i,
$
where
$$
X_i = \begin{cases}
Z_i  &\text{w.p}\; p\\
-Z_i &\text{w.p}\; 1-p
\end{cases}
$$

**Question:** For $b>0, p>1/2$, what is the probability that $S_n > -b,\;\;\forall n>0$? Mathematically,
$$
\mathbb{P}\big(S_n > -b\; \forall n>0 \big)?
$$

**Binary random:** Consider random walk:
$
\tilde{S}_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\tilde{X}_i,
$
where
$
\tilde{X}_i = \begin{cases}
1  &\text{w.p}\; p\\
-1 &\text{w.p}\; 1-p
\end{cases}.
$

**My Conjecture:** The poisson random walk is a "stretched" version of the binary random walk and thus
$\mathbb{P}(\tilde{S}_n>-b\;\;\forall n>0) \leq \mathbb{P}({S}_n>-b\;\;\forall n>0)$.

Comment: It seems unlikely that your conjecture should be correct (although the intuition may not be bad). For example, take $\lambda \to \infty$. Then the $Z_i$ concentrate around $\lambda$, and $\lambda \gg b$, so basically this just says $\Pr(\text{standard biased SRW is always positive})$, which is just the usual escape probability. Now take $\lambda \to 0$. In order to reach a distance $b \gg \lambda$ from $0$, some large number of steps will be taken. By the LLN, may as well replace $\text{Poisson}(\lambda)$ with just $\lambda$. So this probability tends to $1$ (since biased and $b \gg \lambda$).

Comment: On the other hand, your $\mathbb{P}(\tilde{S}_n>-b \: \forall n>0)$ lies between these two (providing $b > 2$). \\ For proceeding with your question, I would note that the sum of independent Poissons is a Poisson. So write $\xi_i = \pm1$ for whether you go up or down. Then all the "ups" sum to get a Poisson distribution, as do the "downs", conditional on how many up/down